# Run Multiple postman collections using newman and yarn

Tags: postman, github-actions, yarnpkg, package.json, newman

I have a scenario where I am running multiple postman collections using newman & yarn in github actions. I need to POST a message on MS teams after the execution.The problem is if One of the test case fails in first collection, the second collection is not running, So I added -x to suppress the exit code to run all collections and publish a report. But even if all the collections are passed I still get a failure message in the Teams POST

Below is my package.jsnn & steps in workflow yml . Any solutions please?

```
{
  "name": "healthcheck",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npx newman run collections/test.postman_collection.json -e environments/test.postman_environment.json -x"
    "test1": "npx newman run collections/test1.postman_collection.json -e environments/test1.postman_environment.json -x"

  
    "test-api": "yarn test",
    "test1-api": "yarn test1"


  },
  "dependencies": {
    "newman": "^5.3.2",
    "newman-reporter-htmlextra": "^1.22.11"
  }
}
```

Worlflow yml

```
  - name: Execute API Health check tests
    id: executeAPITest
    run:
      yarn test-api && yarn test1-api
```

```
- name: postMessageMSTeams
       if: always()
       env:
         TEAMS_WEBHOOK: "lINK"
       run: |
         if ${{ steps.executeAPITest.outcome != 'success' }}; then
          curl -X POST $TEAMS_WEBHOOK -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"title": "healthcheck - FAILED "}
         else
          curl -X POST $TEAMS_WEBHOOK -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"title": "healthcheck - PASSED "}
```

```
     fi
```

Thanks,

I tried adding -x to suppress exit code, It works if one test case fails in and the rest of the collections continue to run and POST a failure message on Teams.But I still get a FAILURE message even if all test are passed.